# RosJava +android?

Tags: ros, java, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i'm developing an App to control a robot running with Ros , to etablish the connection with my robot i'm using and WifiP2Pmanager packages.
the problem is i can't figure out how to interact with th robot, do i need to add packages from ROsjava to my Eclipse IDE ?, or sould  i continue to developing my app first, and after that create android packages On Ros to receive data from my mobile?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131896/rosjava-+android?/) by [shiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/12161/shiro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can get eclipse to pull in whatever rosjava maven dependencies you need or if you want to just drop in some jars, you can download them directly from https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo.

There are various other ways of building your android apps, but given your setup, this is probably the easiest recommendation.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2014-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0